# How to change the color of a div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple items in my website having same class name here is my code for single item price section only

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="prod-price">
                            <span class="price-old" style="display: none;">9.90</span>
                            <span class="price-new">9.90</span>
                        </div>
                        <div style="font-size: 0.8em; padding-top: 4em; display: none;" class="save- sale">0.00</div>
                        <div class="pc"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="prod-price">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="medtext">&nbsp;<b>(Out of Stock)</b></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What i need to do i want to change the color of only for that div(having class name price-new) which has (out of status) message.i tried the below code but it changes the color for all divs having class name price-new i want this script to be apply only for those items which is having out of stock message using either jquery or java script.

this is what i have tried

JS for the code:-

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".medtext").each(function () {
            if ($.trim($(this).text()) == 'Out of Stock') {
                $(".price-new").css("color", "black");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the parent and then find the child :

```
$(function () {
    $(".medtext").each(function(){
        if($.trim($(this).text()) == '(Out of Stock)') {
            $(this).parent().parent().find(".price-new").css("color","red");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this : you can find parent table using `closest()` and then find `price-new` inside `prod-price` div using `.find()`

**NOTE** - You have text as '(Out of Stock)' and comparing with 'Out of Stock', so either put round brackets in text to compare or use indexOf like `if($(this).text().indexOf('Out of Stock')!=-1)`, also you are putting color=black which is already there by default (as I can see in shared code, but it may be different in actual), so try some other color to differentiate. I have used red in DEMO link.

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $("td.medtext").each(function(){
      if($.trim($(this).text()) == '(Out of Stock)') {
       $(this).closest('table').find(".prod-price .price-new").css("color","black");
      }
    });
  });
 </script>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ygcx972y/14/)**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table with multiple pairs of rows, you can do:

```
<script>
  (function($) {
    $(function () {

      $('td.medtext:contains("(Out of Stock)")')
      .closest('tr').prev('tr')
      .find('.prod-price .price-new')
      .css('color', 'black');

    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

This row can be executed even if no tds are in the html at all. No vanilla JS at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare text with '(Out of Stock)' **NOT**  with 'Out of Stock'. == will compare exact text.
Like this `if($.trim($(this).text()) == '(Out of Stock)') {`
    OR
if you want to check 'Out of stock' is present in html element then simply change condition to find substring for e.g.
`if($(this).text().trim().indexOf( '(Out of Stock)') !== -1) {`